# Overriding the default 'No Data' Message in MVCContrib Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Is it possible to override the default 'There is no Data available' message in MVCContrib Grid with a custom message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= Html.Grid<SomeModelType>(Model)
        .Empty("Some custom message")
        ...
%>
```